# MVC3 converting date to string error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to convert date to string I get this error. So how can I fix this error ?

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), new { @class = "date", @required = "required" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date)
   </div>
```

Then I have edited my class with the annotation then same result here is my class. My date parameter in my database table which name is "contents"  which I used in my view "x=>x.date"

```
 public class Common
    {

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

public class CommonModel
        {
            public content content{ get; set; }


        }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use Data Annotations in your class for that? like: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

1) Put Data Annotation in your class like:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

2) Replacing this line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), new { @class = "date", @required = "required" })
```

for this should work:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.date, new { @class = "date", @required = "required" })
```

Comment: Yeap I have add the annation my class but there is no change I'will edit my answer with my class I think I'm missing something but what ?

Comment: Did you change TextBoxFor for EditorFor?

Comment: Yes I have changed and I get this result 21.12.2012 00:00:00 so nothing was changed

Comment: I can't figure out why it happens like that. I have "contents" table and my parameter in contents.date. I have added annotation as you say in my class as you can see in my question

Comment: I just updated my answer...try again using `ApplyFormatInEditMode`